# React dotenv cannot load .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

React + node project, got my .env file in root (along with all other root files like .eslint, .gitignore), it contains 6 lines like `APIKEY=aeofiunoief`, no other special symbols.

In `src/` I have `index.js` which does normal imports (like React, ReactDOM), then `//eslint-disable import/first`, then `require('dotenv').load()`. According to everything I've seen this should load my variables into `process.env`, but when I check console.log, I don't see anything but `NODE_ENV` and `PUBLIC_URL`.

It's really confusing...

Comment: The npm package dotenv should work straight out the box, the latest version of create-react-app I believe should also load your custom environment variables, there is a little trick though you have to prepend the variable with REACT_APP_  Only variables starting with REACT_APP_ are imported. Its a security thing I believe

Answer (score 2):

Your file structure:

```
src
  index.js
  ...
.env
...
```

Do:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });
console.log(process.env);
```

From dotenv GitHub:

> You can specify a custom path if your file containing environment variables is named or located differently.
>
> `require('dotenv').config({path: '/custom/path/to/your/env/vars'})`

Comment: `console.log(__dirname)` gives `/`.

Comment: Nope, Windows in `Documents/projDirectory`.

Comment: Yes I did, gave `/`.

Comment: Sorry, neither of those worked. With or without `.` in the `env` filename, checked that too.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan - This solution works, are you sure you are calling your `process.env` after you have required `dotenv`?

Comment: Turns out the answer was to eject from my create-react-app project and modify env.js to patch through the variables I wanted. Now it works both locally and on my Heroku deployment.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan...Seems I am also stuck with this. Can you post your package,json script part here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the [Dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) webpack plugin and I was pointing to the wrong file path:

```
plugins: [
    htmlWebpackPlugin,
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, .., '.env')
    })
  ],
```

For my structure, `path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env')` was the right configuration that worked. As long as you are pointing to the right `.env` within your system, you should be good.